# I can't keep the client connected to the server or send anything after the first request made by the client

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I can't keep the client connected to the server or send anything after the first request made by the client. And I know it is because I shutdown and close my socket at 'SendCallback' method, but else it will spam messages to the client until the client refuses the connection. **What can I do to fix this?** Hope I was clear enough with my explanation.

```
public class StateObject
{
// Client  socket.
public Socket workSocket = null;
// Size of receive buffer.
public const int BufferSize = 1024;
// Receive buffer.
public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
// Thread signal.
public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public static ArrayList terminal = new ArrayList();

private List<StateObject> clients;

public AsynchronousSocketListener()
{
}

public static void StartListening()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("192.168.1.75");
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 10008);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Terminal Connected");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        content = state.sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine( content );

        Send(handler);
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Failed to collect data.");
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            // Code would loop, leaving the server without answer.
            /*handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);*/
     }

}

private static void Send(Socket handler)
{
    String data = String.Empty;

    Console.WriteLine("Sent Back:");
    data = ("002BSLL01V01000     DF02V0110");
    Console.WriteLine(data);

    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

        Send(handler);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}


public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

> I know it is because I shutdown and close my socket at 'SendCallback' method

Of course it is.

> but else it will spam messages to the client

Define 'spam messages to the client'.

> until the client refuses the connection.

You mean the client *closes* the connection? The connection already exists, it can't be 'refused'.

> What can I do to fix this?

Don't close the socket; don't shut it down; and fix the *problem* described by 'spam messages to the client', whatever that means.

> Hope I was clear enough with my explanation.

Not in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the data in the ReadCallback, you then (even if you haven't received all the data you are expecting) call Send(), which then does an async send, in the send callback you then call Send() again, this, I think, is what you mean by spamming the client, as this will just loop around sending the same thing to the client over and over.

I suggest you check what you have received in the first place, it's entirely possible that the call to receive won't return all the data you are expecting in one go. Then don't call Send in the SendCallback if you don't want to send the data to the client again.

Oh, and remove the calls to shutdown and close the socket...